# Changing background color of Ionic list item on hover in CSS

Tags: html, angularjs, css, ionic-framework

I am using the Ionic framework for a mobile web application. I'm trying to change the background color of an Ionic list item on hover, but it won't change.

This is what's in my html:

```
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" href="#/newpage">               
                <div>{{item.color}}</div>                       
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

This is what's in the CSS:

```
ion-item:hover {

    background-color: red;
    border-color: red;
}
```

The border color kind of works, but it only highlights the left, top, and right border of the item, not the bottom border. The background color does not change at all on hover. Is there a possibility that the href tag in the ion-item disables the CSS? If I remove the href tag, it works fine.

I've looked online for help, but no where have I found a solution or explanation to this problem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `href` attribute on the `ion-item` will generate the following HTML (stripped some attributes for clarity):

```
<ion-item href="#/newpage">
  <a ng-href="#/newpage" target="_self" href="#/newpage">
    <div class="ng-binding">Something</div>
  </a>
</ion-item>
```

You need to change the background color for the `a` element:

```
ion-item.item:hover a {
  background-color: slategray;
}
```

Note that the `.item` part is used to give the selector higher specificity. Otherwise the default background color for `.item` would be used instead.

Could also be solved with `!important`, but I prefer the former:

```
ion-item:hover a {
  background-color: slategray !important;
}
```

To style the border is trickier since the list elements have various margins depending on the position in the list (first, last or other). It's possible to counter this but it would push the adjacent elements 1px when one is hovered. Might be possible to solve this as well but it would probably require a bunch of new CSS.

An alternative solution is to use an inset box-shadow instead:

```
ion-item.item:hover a {
  background-color: slategray;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px red;
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/TCRbWhIQ6xJRx2qrgExs?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

to Modify the background color of default ionic list items you will need to use these selectors with `!important` , it also depends whether you are using `href` property or not

**with `href`:**

Changing the color of normal items

```
 .item-complex .item-content, .item{
    background-color: #d8dfe6 !important;
}
```

and on hover

```
.item-complex .item-content:hover{
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

**Without `href`:**

Changing the color of normal items

```
 .item{
    background-color: #d8dfe6 !important;
}
```

and on hover

```
.item:hover{
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ionic 4 this is what worked for me using the `--background-hover` css variable.

```css
#css
:host {
  ion-item:hover { 
    --background-hover: #000000 #color of choice 
  }
}

#scss
:host {
  ion-item {
    &:hover {
      --background-hover: #000000 #color of choice
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is the correct answer for all new(er|est) versions of Ionic (currently v6.x).

Answer (score 1):

In Ionic 4, one updates the variables.**scss** respectively the CSS custom property of the ion-item tag/component - if you want it to be customized for your entire app and not just a specifi item list. Otherwise append an id or class name.

```
ion-item:hover {
  --background: #efefef;
}
```

Otherwise append an id or class name. 
`ion-item#myid:hover` or `ion-item.myclass:hover`

For others properties see: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item#css-custom-properties

Every Ionic tag has these properties to customize.

Comment: Did work for me in ionic v7 

Answer (score 1):

**10-07-2020**

**Ionic 5 / Capacitor** this works for me:

*html*

```
<ion-menu-toggle autoHide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages; let i = index">

        <ion-item (click)="selectedIndex = i" [class.selected]="selectedIndex == i" button="true"
          (click)="goToPage(p)" class="my-hover">

          <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.ionicIcon? p.ionicIcon: ''"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>
            {{p.title}}
          </ion-label>

        </ion-item>

      </ion-menu-toggle>
```

*css*

```
ion-item {
  --background-hover: var(--ion-color-primary);
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me in ionic v7 ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

For the most basic approach put this in globals. (adding class item-hover to some thing...)

```
<ion-item class="item-hover">some thing...</ion-item>

ion-item.item-hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    --background: #cccccc;
  }
}
```

It is always best to use a custom utility class as to not affect other areas like form input wrappers etc...

Cheers!